# Cannot get Time Ago in real time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react native and i want to get the "Time ago" in near real time. (ex: 1 minute ago, 3 hours ago etc.)

My problem is i am facing difficulties to tell my app it must refresh the date every X seconds.

```
  componentDidMount(){

  setInterval(() => {
    this.refresh()
    },30000)


}

refresh = () => {
   content = <Text note>{this.getTimeAgo()}</Text>
    return content
}

getTimeAgo = () => {
  //doing stuff to format then
  return TimeAgo
}
```

Actually it works but only once (the first 30 seconds and after it no longer update (getTimeAgo() is no longer called).

So i don't know why it call getTimeAgo() once , i need it to be called at least every 30 seconds.

What i have missed ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where would it return *to*? Set up a state value (probably called `timeAgo`?), make the component update that state value every 30 seconds, so that React retriggers `render()`, and then in your render function tap into that value to present it to your users:

```
class TimerThing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeAgo: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.setTimeAgo(),30000)
  }

  render() {
    return <Text note>{this.state.timeAgo}</Text>
  }

  setTimeAgo() {
    var timeAgo;

    // ...do computy things...

    this.setState({ timeAgo });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `setState` and then using the value of that item in state as the content of your component?

Something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.setState({timeAgo: this.getTimeAgo()});
}, 30000);
```

And in the `return` of the `render` method, include

```
{this.state.timeAgo}
```

where you want the time to be displayed.